# excel file merge with sheets in python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to append many excel files with `sheet1` and `sheet2`.
I have written the following code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

files = os.listdir("C:/Python27/files")
files
df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2')
    df = df.append(data)
```

example names of the files :`Total Apr 2014,Total Aug 2014`

The following is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/filemerge2.py", line 10, in <module>
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 170, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 227, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 395, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Total Apr 2014.xls'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python `os.listdir` will return a list containing the **relative names** of files inside the given directory. If you are running your script from a folder other than `"C:/Python27/files"` (or whatever folder your xls files are located), then you need to give it the full path to the required file to the `read_excel()` function (or whatever file management function you call).

To make your script work, just append the base folder to the file name and it should work:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder = "C:/Python27/files"
files = os.listdir(folder)
files
df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(folder + '/' + f, 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2')
    df = df.append(data)
```

Notice that `os.listdir` will return all files and directories inside `folder`, regardless of their types. Make sure to perform some file type checking before trying to open it with `read_excel()` (or just use a `try-except` block around the contents of your for loop that depend on this call).

Comment: Thanks @csantos .I got a new error now.                                                           `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/filemerge2.py", line 9, in <module>
    data = pd.read_excel(folder + '/' + f, 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 178, in read_excel
    squeeze=squeeze, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 434, in _parse_excel
    data[header] = _trim_excel_header(data[header])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: From [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html), it seems that the third parameter to `read_excel` must be an integer or a list of ints, but you're passing `'Sheet2'` instead.